# Можно ли написать контракт для уже существующего контракта на ERC20?

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, ethereum

Есть токен ERC20 и естественно его родной контракт.
Вообще, в тегории под этот существующий контракт можно ли написать свой контракт?

Тоесть что мы мой контракт общался с контрактом оригинала?

Если подробней, сейчас всплеск пирамид (классические МММ) работающих на эфире. Высылаешь Эфир, и через сутки приходит % с платежа.

В теории, можно ли такой сделать для токена ERC20?
Общаюсь с потенциальным разработчиком, показывает пример контракта. В котором продублирован контракт оригинального контракта (с которым нужна связка) и + следом мои "хотелки".

Как я понимаю такой контракт, это просто копия-пустышка.
Которая автономно и независима, это токены с такого микса не оригинальны и стоит ровно ничего.

Просвятите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

> Тоесть что бы мой контракт общался с контрактом оригинала?

Можно. "Общение" между контрактами - это всего лишь транзакция в сети эфириума.

> Высылаешь Эфир, и через сутки приходит % с платежа.

Если есть возможность прислать эфир, значит так же можно присылать любые другие токены. Просто нужна транзакция, которая вызовет метод `transfer` вашего ERC20 контракта на нужный адрес.